# Рост уровней игры

Tags: java, android, разработка-игр

Пытаюсь  реализовать расчет получения новых уровней. За каждое действие игрок получает определенное количество очков, от 1 до 8, плюс еще за нужную комбинацию этих действий даются очки. Понятно, что чем сложней действие, тем больше очков он получит.
Как  в таком случае написать алгоритм, что бы при получении нового уровня значение  `next_lvl` возвращалось только один раз? Так как от это влияет на выполнение еще нескольких методов.

```
       protected int next_lvl = 1;
       protected int LVL_UP(int income) {
        if (income >= 15 && income <= 20) {
            this.next_lvl = 2;
        } else if (income >= 21 && income <= 40) {
            this.next_lvl = 3;
        } else if (income >= 41 && income <= 60) {
            this.next_lvl = 4;
        }  
        return next_lvl;
        }
```

Comment: Уточните вопрос. У вас и сейчас `next_lvl` возвращается один раз. Вообще на вашем месте я бы создал в классе переменную `experience`, и добавил бы метод, который изменяет этот опыт. После этого можно сделать либо метод расчета уровня по текущему опыту, либо переменную уровня и метод ее обновления от текущего значения переменной `experience`

Comment: У меня проверка уровня завязана кнопку завершения действия. И получается, что  игрок наибрает 16 очков -  метод возвращает "2" и при наборе 19 очков тоже возвращается "2". А нужно, что бы если один раз  метод вернул набранный уровень, больше его не возвращал. Пытался  использовать флаги, но не вышло. Собственно  ```income``` и является переменной опыта.  Все расчеты уровней, достижений, комбинаций и т.д. вынесены в отдельный класс.

Comment: Я бы попросил у вас немного больше кода, чтобы было хоть что воспроизвести, но пока что я вижу следующее решение: у вас должен быть класс Player. Добавьте в него приватную переменную `experience` и методы `void add_exp(int delta)` и `int get_lvl()`, после чего используйте уже их при присвоении опыта

Comment: Остальной код к этому расчету не ведь не относится, я не знаю даже  что и скидывать. Тут проблема в чем. Как один раз возвращать получаемый уровень?   Накопил игрок 16 очков, получил лвлАп.   Потом он получает 19 очков - и нового ЛвлАпа быть не должно. И  как этого не допустить?

Comment: Но данная функция всегда должна хоть что-то возвращать, поэтому, к примеру, что она вернет, если уровень не повысится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опишу свою идею в ответе. Надеюсь, что вы найдете тут что-то для решения своей проблемы:

У вас так или иначе должен быть класс `Player`, который обладает этими уровнями и так далее, поэтому все вычисления уровня и прибавления опыта лучше реализовать внутри этого класса, а не внутри функций, обозначающих действия игрока.

```
public class Player
{
    private int exp_points = 0;

    public void addExperience(int income)
    {
        this.exp_points += income;
        if (this.exp_points < 0)
            this.exp_points = 0;
    }

    public int getLevel()
    {
        if (this.exp_points < 15)
            return 1;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 20)
            return 2;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 40)
            return 3;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 60)
            return 4;
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Или аналогично:

```
public class Player
{
    private int exp_points = 0;
    private int lvl = 1;

    public void addExperience(int income)
    {
        this.exp_points += income;
        if (this.exp_points < 0)
            this.exp_points = 0;

        this.updateLevel();
    }

    private void updateLevel()
    {
        if (this.exp_points < 15)
            this.lvl = 1;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 20)
            this.lvl = 2;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 40)
            this.lvl = 3;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 60)
            this.lvl = 4;
        else
            this.lvl = 5;
    }

    public int getLevel()
    {
        return this.lvl;
    }
}
```

Тогда при реализации функции, обозначающей действие игрока, можно использовать уже реализованные в классе методы:

```
void playerAction1(Player player)
{
    //...

    player.addExperience(15);
}
```

Если при этом вы хотите проверять, получил ли игрок новый уровень, то это можно достичь отдельным методом или, например, так:

```
public class Player
{
    private int exp_points = 0;
    private int lvl = 1;

    public boolean addExperience(int income)
    {
        this.exp_points += income;
        if (this.exp_points < 0)
            this.exp_points = 0;

        return this.updateLevel();
    }

    private boolean updateLevel()
    {
        int old_lvl = this.lvl;

        if (this.exp_points < 15)
            this.lvl = 1;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 20)
            this.lvl = 2;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 40)
            this.lvl = 3;
        else if (this.exp_points <= 60)
            this.lvl = 4;
        else
            this.lvl = 5;

        return (this.lvl > old_lvl);
    }

    public int getLevel() {}
}

void playerAction1(Player player)
{
    //...

    if (player.addExperience(15))
        //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Метод расчёта уровня по `income` можно сделать статическим. Для вывода сообщения о повышении уровня можно сделать другой метод, в котором будет проверяться, что уровень увеличился. Насколько я понял, вы хотите что-то такое получить?

```
protected int next_lvl = 1;

protected static int LVL_UP(int income) {
  if (income >= 15 && income <= 20) {
    return 2;
  } else if (income >= 21 && income <= 40) {
    return 3;
  } else if (income >= 41 && income <= 60) {
    return 4;
  }  
  return 1;
}

void printIfLeveledUp(int income) {
  int new_lvl = LVL_UP(income);
  if (new_lvl > next_lvl) {
    next_lvl = new_lvl;
    System.out.println(next_lvl);
  }
}
```